# "content: attr" não valida no W3C

Tags: html, css, validação, w3c-validador

Como resolver esse erro na linha `table td:before {content: attr(db);` que faz com o que não valide no [W3C](https://www.w3.org/)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
table {width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
table tr {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;}
table th, table td {padding: 10px;text-align: center;}

@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {
table {border: 0;}
table thead {display: none;}
table tr {margin-bottom: 10px;display: block;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
table td {display: block; text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
table td:last-child {border-bottom: 0;}
table td:before {content: attr(db);float: left;font-weight: bold;}}
</style>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Data de Nasc.</th>
<th>Salário</th>
<th>Cargo</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td db="Nome">Adão</td>
<td db="Data de Nasc.">01/01/1980</td>
<td db="Salário">R$ 1.250,00</td>
<td db="Cargo">Auxiliar de produção</td></tr>
<tr>
<td db="Nome">Eva</td>
<td db="data de Nasc.">01/01/1980</td>
<td db="Salário">R$ 2.500,00</td>
<td db="Cargo">Gerente</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Rose eu entendi agora você trocou por isto `{content: "NOME: ";}`, mas entenda isto `{content: "NOME: ";}` é diferente disto `{content: attr(db);}`, é totalmente possivel validar o `{content: attr(db);}` em http://www.css-validator.org como eu disse na resposta, mas se o alternativo lhe resolveu ok. :)

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! A melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou é assinalando a melhor resposta como aceita e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil pra todo mundo.

Answer (score 5):

Vou arriscar a dizer que há um erro no **Validador**, pois as documentações ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation), [CDN Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/attr), [CND Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_gen_content)), dão vastos exemplos de como usar o **attr** em **content**, e estes exemplos não validam, pode testar. Então vai a dica comenta a linha /*{content: attr(db);*/ e valida, vai dar certo (levando em consideração o erro do validador).

Para fazer de acordo com os padrões HTML 4, o elemento **td** não possuí atributo **db** ([vide Documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp)), utilize então o **abbr** ([vide Documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_abbr.asp)) no lugar do **db**.

```
content: attr(abbr);

<td abbr="Nome">Adão</td>
```

Em resumo, comente a linha valide e seja feliz, pois nem a documentação da organização que valida está válida :).

Para HTML 5 use a dica do **[Afonso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4279/afonso-alban)** abaixo:

Comment: Ta certo valeu a dica.. já consegui resolver de outra maneira no <td coloquei um class="c1" e no style .c1::before {content: "NOME: ";} fiz uma modificações e agora esta como eu queria um CSS nível 3 ! sem erros de validação.

Answer (score 4):

O erro do validador é justamente com o atributo `db`, porém não existe nenhum erro nesse código `CSS`.

A ressalva está, justamente, nos atributos `db` e `abbr`. O atributo `db` não existe, e para esses casos o padrão orienta que se use o prefixo `data-`, ou seja, o atributo deveria ser escrito como `data-db`. Através deste prefixo podemos escrever qualquer atributo que não esteja na especificação do `HTML`.

Além disso, o `abbr` sugerido em outra resposta não faz mais parte da especificação e não deve mais ser utilizado. Está obsoleto desde a versão 5 do HTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

Comment: O erro não é no atributo db, é do validador mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Realmente existe um problema é na hora de validar pelo https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator ele mostra este erro:

> Value Error : content Parse Error attr(db)

Como na imagem:

<kbd>[image: jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator]</kbd>

O valor `attr` no `content:` não era suportado até algum tempo, mas hoje já é parte do CSS3, então se trata de um BUG https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/24

No entanto se tentar validar em http://www.css-validator.org/ ele funciona normalmente (selecione em <kbd>More Options</kbd> > <kbd>Profile :</kbd> a opção CSS level 3, porque senão ele vai usar a versão 2.1) ele irá validar normalmente, veja o resultado:

<kbd>[image: css-validador.org]</kbd>

### Considerações sobre o HTML

- **não** use `abbr=`, ele está em desuso no html5.
- O atributo `db` é invalido.
- Ao invés de `db=""` use o atributo `data-` que é especifico pra este tipo de tarefa.

Agora informações adicionais:

- Falta as tags `<body>`, `<head>` e `<title>` se não ele não valida

### HTML e CSS validos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exemplo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        table {width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
        table tr {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px;}
        table th, table td {padding: 10px;text-align: center;}

        @media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {
            table {border: 0;}
            table thead {display: none;}
            table tr {margin-bottom: 10px;display: block;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
            table td {display: block; text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
            table td:last-child {border-bottom: 0;}
            table td:before {content: attr(data-db);float: left;font-weight: bold;}
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data de Nasc.</th>
        <th>Salário</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-db="Nome">Adão</td>
    <td data-db="Data de Nasc.">01/01/1980</td>
    <td data-db="Salário">R$ 1.250,00</td>
    <td data-db="Cargo">Auxiliar de produção</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-db="Nome">Eva</td>
    <td data-db="data de Nasc.">01/01/1980</td>
    <td data-db="Salário">R$ 2.500,00</td>
    <td data-db="Cargo">Gerente</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Validado 100% em:

- https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
- http://www.css-validator.org/

### Dicas:

- Realmente é bom validar o CSS e o HTML, mas não é tão importante assim, tem coisas como esta que funcionam mas não validam, então prefira apenas se importar se o CSS funciona em todos navegadores que deseja, mesmo que não valide.
- Estão aparecendo muitas novas funcionalidade no CSS, nem tudo estará listado no validador e podem aparecer estes *falsos problemas*.

Resumindo, tente validar o que der, mas se algo falhar não se prenda tanto a isto, desde que funcione em todos navegadores que seus clientes usam (de preferencia os mais modernos) então estará tudo bem.